# ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sqoop

I am receiving an error when connecting mysql and I do not know the steps to connect the driver. I am using AWS EMR as a student. My intention is to run some pig commands after I connect.

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-88-249 ~]$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://retail-db.cjmn8pjxazxq.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/retail --table customers --username admin --password ***** --target-dir SQP/input/sqoop1 -m 1
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
22/10/26 02:30:38 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
22/10/26 02:30:39 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
22/10/26 02:30:39 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
22/10/26 02:30:39 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
22/10/26 02:30:39 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:875)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1872)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1671)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:501)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

I was not able to find a step by step process to add the driver for AWS EMR

Answer (score 0):

EMR is just a handful of Linux servers that you have SSH access to.

Sqoop is just a JVM application.

You add the JDBC driver to its classpath (i.e. it's lib directory)